# How can I execute the action of a custom Ribbon control in MS Office/PowerPoint from within a C# add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, ribbon, ribbon-control

I'm currently writing a PowerPoint 2010 C# add-in using VSTO. I am trying to execute a number of Ribbon controls which are there through custom add-ins from within my own C# add-in.

For example, to find the following control and execute its click event, how would I do it?:

Insert tab -> "Addin X" group -> "Do it" button

I've looked into using the Accessibility interface but am totally unfamiliar and would be at it all day. If someone knows how to knock together the code, I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. The ribbon is meant to use the other way, with user actions triggering your code. That said, what is it you want to do? You need to explain in more detail, maybe there is another way to go about it?

Comment: Hi Olle -- thanks for the reply.

There is an existing add-in (for which I do not have the source code) which performs several functions which I need to call in my add-in.

The best way of doing this that I can see would be to call the Ribbon events in some way -- either through some direct interface (which I can't find), sending user keys to trigger the shortcut, using the Accessibility interface, or the COM interface (not possible here as methods aren't exposed in the other add-in).

I know that the Accessibility method works, just I'm not familiar enough to do it easily myself.

Comment: Ok, then I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @ChrisAdams what solution did you end up using?